# PyQT: QPushButton delegate in column of a treeview

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt, treeview

I know there has been a question with the same goal in [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38796335/qpushbuttons-in-a-column-of-a-treeview), but I didn't succeed implementing a button delegate in a treeview. So I ask a new question here, even if I know there was a previous question with the same goal. I just ask for further explanation.

So since a few days, I manage to implement a multi-node tree model within a treeview thanks to this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GDB2PuJ4_7s) with the code source [here](http://www.yasinuludag.com/PyQt/Tutorial04/Tutorial04_TreeModel.py) and [here](http://www.yasinuludag.com/PyQt/Tutorial04/icons_rc.py) but now I would like to add a delegate pushbutton next to each child of the **last** level of the tree model. After consulting Qt documentation about model/view programming, searching [around](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/embedding-iconic-pushButton-in-TableView-and-or-TreeView-td1917364.html) and reading chapter 14, 15 and 16 from the book of Mark Summerfield [Rapid GUI Programming with Python and QT](https://www.google.fr/search?client=firefox-b&dcr=0&q=rapid+gui+programming+with+python+and+qt:+the+definitive+guide+to+pyqt+programming&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgecToyS3w8sc9YSmHSWtOXmO04uIKzsgvd80rySypFNLhYoOylLgEpHj00_UNjZJy0zMsDZI0GKT4uFBEeADe5rqGTgAAAA&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjypNbtlY_YAhWFthQKHXHOBBMQ6RMIlQEwCw&biw=1366&bih=607) and searching how to add Qwidget delegate by using `createEditor()`, `setEditordata()` and `setModelData()` I still struggle to display "The" button…

So I started to create the button class delegate:

```
class ButtonDelegate(QtGui.QItemDelegate):
    """
    A delegate that places a fully functioning Button in every
    cell of the column to which it's applied
    """

    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtGui.QItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        button = QtGui.QPushButton("Simple button", parent)
        self.connect(button, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self, QtCore.SLOT("handle_button()"))
        return button

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def handle_button(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        print("Button pushed: {}".format(self.sender()))
```

Here you see that I didn't implement `setEditordata()` and `setModelData()`, because I have connected the button to `def handle_button(self)` and I just want to print the name of the child for the moment (just to make it simple).

I use `setItemDelegateForColumn(int, AbstractItemDelegate)` for setting up the delegate I also know that for displaying the button you have to specify this method to the treeview `QAbstractItemView.openPersistentEditor(QModelIndex)`. But I don't know what to put as argument...

Again I am sorry to "repost" a question but at the moment I am in a dead end...I don't know where to start.

I write my code in Python, but if you answer in C++ I will figure it out, don't worry.

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: A delegate will only be visible when actually *editing* an item. An [index widget](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#setIndexWidget) might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `setIndexWidget` might be a solution, but since you have to set it for *every* last child item, this might require too much coding and could be prone to bugs and headaches...
I'd suggest to draw the button directly in the delegate using QStyle's methods.

This is a simple implementation:

```
class ButtonDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)
        if index.model().hasChildren(index):
            return
        rect = option.rect
        btn = QtGui.QStyleOptionButton()
        btn.rect = QtCore.QRect(rect.left() + rect.width() - 30, rect.top(), 30, rect.height())
        btn.text = '...'
        btn.state = QtGui.QStyle.State_Enabled|(QtGui.QStyle.State_MouseOver if option.state & QtGui.QStyle.State_MouseOver else QtGui.QStyle.State_None)
        QtGui.QApplication.style().drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_PushButton, btn, painter)
```

And here's how it could look like...

[image: Example of implementation]

Obviously you have to implement your own signal, but, since `editorEvent` automatically handles mouse events, this would be a simple task of detecting if the `event.pos()` is within the "virtual" button `QRect`.

In the example above I added a simple hover detection, which sets the "mouse-over look" on the button whenever the mouse pointer is above the item, but you might prefer to use the hover style only when the pointer is actually on the button.

Since `paint` doesn't give you the possibility to detect the mouse position, there are two possible solutions. Either you use a delegate exclusively for the view and add the view's instance as a parameter when you init the delegate (then you can easily use `mapFromGlobal` with `QtGui.QCursor.pos()` and retrieve its position according to the `option.rect` - just remember that you have to map it to the `viewport`, not the view); or you create a specific *UserRole* in which you write the `event.pos()` to the item from the `editorEvent` method, then read it from the `paint` method. To achieve that, `mouseTracking` must be enabled on the view.

### Some further comments

As you can imagine, the look of the item will have issues when the tree level is too deep and the view's width isn't wide enough to show the item itself. You could look into the `option.rect`'s available size, if you don't want to hide the item or don't show the button if there's not enough space available.

Another drawback is that the item's text might be painted over by the button, with some styles this could result in some ugly appearance. You could decide to elide the text using fontMetrics' `elideText()` method (by subctracting the button's width) or simply "mask" the right side of the button if the fontMetrics of the item's text does not allow it to be completely shown.

Be careful with that, though: if you have more than one column, the "hidden" right part of the button won't be hidden at all, but it will be part of the next column.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @musicamante I will take a look at the `paint()` method and `edtiorevent()` ;)

Comment: Note that in the example above I was drawing "over" the already drawn delegate (the class's `QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate.paint` call at the beginning). If you need more control over the drawing, you will have to instantiate the QStyleOptionViewItem, init it using the option argument and eventually use QStyledItemDelegate.initStyleOption. Also, remember that `option`'s properties behave like python properties: their values are read and set as normal variables and not with function calls.

Comment: I thought for handling button clicked, get inspired by those answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777637/adding-button-to-qtableview) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37972839/dynamic-qtreeview-with-custom-delegates?rq=1). The final goal of my treeview is to add a QLineEdit in anoter column and these button. For the QlineEdit I found several references on the net, or I will simply just allowed the column to be editable. The main problem was how to handle button as delegate ;)